# convert cordova files path to File object

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, jquery-file-upload

I am trying to build a simple photo upload app on Ionic (Cordova). I am using the cordovaImagePicker plugin to have the user select images from the mobile device. This plugin returns an array of paths on the device.

For handling the upload part I am using jquery-file-upload (mostly because that is what I used for the browser version and I am doing all kinds of processing for which I have the code ready). The problem is however that jquery-file-upload expects to work with an input element `<input type="file">` which creates a javascript File object containing all kinds of metadata.

So in order to get the cordovaImagePicker to work with jquery-file-upload, I figure I have to convert the filepath to a File object. Below I am using the cordova file plugin to achieve this:

```
$cordovaImagePicker.getPictures($scope.pickOptions).then(function(filelist) {
  $.each(filelist, function (index, filepath) {
    $window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(filepath, function(fileEntry) {
      fileEntry.file(function(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(e) {
          fileObj = new File([this.result],"filename.jpg",{type: "image/jpeg"});
          // send filelist from cordovaImagePicker to jquery-fileupload as if through file input
          $('#fileupload').fileupload('send', {files: fileObj});
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
      }, function(e){$scope.errorHandler(e)});
    }, function(e){$scope.errorHandler(e)});
  });
}, function(error) {
  // error getting photos
  console.log('Error selecting images through $cordovaImagePicker');
});
```

So first of all this is not really working correctly, apparently I am doing doing something wrong, since for example the type attribute ends up being another object that contains the type attribute with the correct values (and other such weird issues). I would be happy if someone could point out what I am doing wrong.

Surely there must be something (cordova plugin?) that I am not aware of that does this conversion for me (including for example adding a thumbnail)? Alternatively, maybe there is something that can easily make jquery-file-upload work with filepaths? I couldn't find anything so far...

However, it feels I am trying too hard here to force connecting two components that were just not built to work together (File objects vs filepath) and I should maybe just rewrite the processing and use the cordova file transfer plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up rewriting the uploader with the cordova-file-transfer which works like a charm. I wasted more time trying to work around it than just rewriting it from scratch.